# JMeter - Run an amount of thread groups at a time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Basically, I have 30 thread groups in my test plan and I would like to run 8 thread groups at a time consecutively until the test plan is done.

The main test plan options only allow parallel testing of all threads of 1 thread group at a time.

Is there any other way to achieve this apart from segmenting the thread groups in different JMX files or toggling them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm entirely sure what you mean but I'm going to assume you want to run 8 thread groups simultaneously for a certain period, and than start another 8 thread groups and run those for a certain period etc.

You could do this quite easily with the Stepping Thread Group plugin: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/. You can adjust each thread group's start and end time.